# In ASP.NET what is the name for HTML directive symbols <%# or <%= etc for executing code on the server side?

Tags: asp.net

Was trying to reference this the other day, and I've heard them called several things.

They are intrinsically hard to google for. Does this syntax have a proper name? Thanks!

Comment: You would probably have better luck googling for what you are trying to achieve, rather than the symbol name, such as adding a directive, data-binding, etc.

Comment: There appears to be very little consensus here on what these are called, even from msdn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Visual Web Developer Team calls them "[Code Nuggets](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx)," but I don't think there's an official term that'll help you find them in MSDN.

You might be interested in the following MSDN articles:

- [Code Render Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx)
- [Data-Binding Expression Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx)
- [Web Forms Syntax Reference](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/pages/syntax.aspx#expressions)

Answer (score 4):

I call all variations of `<% %>` server tags. Dont know if they have another name.

Answer (score 4):

I've always known them as "Expressions" (and/or "Code Expressions", "ASP.NET Expressions", and a few other variations).

Answer (score 3):

I've heard that they are called constructs.

Answer (score 3):

I think they don't have a collective name. The links to MSDN in [this article](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx) all call them with different names - Embedded Code Blocks (pure <% %>), construct (<%= %>), Data-binding syntax (<%# %>), ASP.NET Expressions (<%$ %>, Directives (<%@ ... %>), Server-side comments ( <%-- ... --%> ). The article itself calls them inline ASP.NET tags.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no common name for these constructions, but we use **inline asp.net tags** (* found a while ago [here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)).

Comment: I've always heard them called "inline tags" as well.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN refers to them as [Embedded Code Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).